# Pass function reference to child

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a generic paginable table component, which recieves as an input the function it should use to retrieve elements when needed (for ex when user clicks next page)

The parent declares the function as:

```
this.getDataFunction = this.service.getByEmail.bind(this.service);
```

the function has the following type:

```
type GetDataFunction = (limit: number, nextKey: string) => Observable<any[]>;
```

I want to use @Output and @Input whenever possible, I guess I could do something like

```
<my-table [currentData]="data" (nextpage)="..." (previousPage)="...">
```

but I would need to reimplement the functions each time I want to use the component, I went with the first option as I would need to only pass the getDataFunction, are there any other alternatives?

Comment: If it's the same data, can you not put it in the service and call it from the component? And then trigger that function call from any parent using `ViewChild`

Comment: The data changes depending on the context, for instance a table of people and a table of cars.